# TSQL setting XML type as NULL if empty variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that is relying on an `IF @awardEmployees IS NOT NULL` statement.

I have the variable defined at the top:

```
@awardEmployees XML = NULL
```

and then before the statement I am trying to set this:

```
SET @awardEmployees = NULLIF(@awardEmployees, '')
```

Which is returning the error:

> The data types xml and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.

My code sends either an XML string or an empty string based on if anything was entered in the search field so I am trying to set it to NULL if it was empty.

Any other ways to accomplish this?

Comment: Does this work?  SET @awardEmployees = NULLIF(CAST(@awardEmployees AS varchar(max)), '')

Comment: That seemed to work! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the exist exist() method - it will return 0, representing False, if it returns an empty result:

```
declare @awardEmployees XML = '<employees><employee><empID>1234</empID></employee></employees>'

IF @awardEmployees.exist('/employees/employee') > 0
BEGIN
    print '@awardEmployees IS NOT NULL'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    print '@awardEmployees IS NULL'
END 


declare @awardEmployees2 XML = ''

IF @awardEmployees2.exist('/employees/employee') > 0 
BEGIN
    print '@awardEmployees2 IS NOT NULL'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    print '@awardEmployees2 IS NULL'
END
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx).

Comment: My XML is `<employees><empolyee><empID>1234</empID></employee></employees>`. So would it be: `IF @awardEmployees.exist('/employees/employee') IS NOT NULL` ?

Comment: @SBB yes, that is my understanding. But you have a typo in your XML.

Comment: <empolyee> should be <employee>

Comment: This may not work after all - `@awardEmployees` will never be null because it will be passed as an empty string to the SP

Comment: In your example, if you set it like so `declare @awardEmployees XML = ''` thats what mine will be if no employees are sent from the front end which still returns is not null

Comment: I have changed it to check if the return value is greater than 0. exist() will return 0, representing False, if it returns an empty result.